# Create a React Native app with no Typescript? (Could not get BatchedBridge)

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I created a project with react native to try typescript, running this command:

> npx react-native init  --template react-native-template-typescript

Now, everytime I create a project just using "npx react-native init ", without the template, it won't work unless I use typescript. Even projects I had previosly created in react native only with javascript won't show up in the android studio virtual device.

I always get this error:

> Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

I have already tried to install react-native again, created multiple new projects from scratch, ran "yarn", "yarn start", "yarn android". I have deleted node modules and installed everything again. I have cleaned the cache. Nothing seems to work.

I have react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and react-native: 0.63.4